# Searching a table by a string

Tags: matlab

I am searching a table by a string, but I am not finding the result even though I'm 100% sure it is there. Running `genelist` prints the table:

```
>> Untitled

genelist = 

    Prot_Family     Gene  
    ___________    _______

    'Prx'          'PRDX1'
    'Prx'          'PRDX2'
    'Prx'          'PRDX3'
    'Trx'          'TXN'  
    'Trx'          'TXN2'
```

But running this command does not find the string: `find(strcmp('PRDX2',genelist(:,2)))`

and `strcmp('PRDX2',genelist(:,2))` returns 0.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When ever I see a screenshot of code or console output I want to down vote immediately, but I try to restrain myself and wait a bit. Please, a plain text copy is always much better! :)

Comment: Okies, sorry for that! :P Editing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because when you index a table, even if everything on those index ranges are the same type, MATLAB will return just another table. Including `genelist(1,1)` will return just a table with a single value on it.

This is because tables are more than just the information they contain in each of the locations. They also have column/row names and a bunch of other information on how to handle them.

Thus, if you want to compare strings from a index range that you know is a string, you need to convert it to string. Use `table2array` as:

```
find(strcmp('PRDX2',table2array(genelist(:,2))))
```

Comment: A slightly simpler fix here is to use `{}` indexing.  That is, try `find(strcmp('PRDX2',genelist{:,2}))`.  This also won't make any deep copies.